# Mysql Join Where Clause duplicate results

Tags: mysql, join

I have a simple SQL join that is duplicating data in the results. One table query:

```
select * from ohyeah_borrower_prefs where inumber=13522
```

Return 3 rows correctly.

```
   ID      Num     iNum       Cat       Subcat         Date         Code
'14332', '13522', '13522', 'Fiction', 'Espionage', '2011-04-04', 'BRAILLE'
'14333', '13522', '13522', 'Fiction', 'Espionage', '2011-04-04', '2 TRACK'
'14334', '13522', '13522', 'Fiction', 'Espionage', '2013-07-18', 'LARGE PRIN'
```

However, if I try this join to my items table to pull the unique barcode, I get 9 results instead of the 3 I would expect - see each results is repeated 3 times!

```
select code, items.barcode from ohyeah_borrower_prefs 
LEFT JOIN items ON
`items`.`inumber` = `ohyeah_borrower_prefs`.`inumber` 
WHERE (`ohyeah_borrower_prefs`.`biblionumber` = 13522)
```

Results:

```
 CODE          BARCODE
BRAILLE       90004071
BRAILLE       30025000162744
BRAILLE       30025000128349
"2 TRACK",    90004071
"2 TRACK",    30025000162744
"2 TRACK",    30025000128349
"LARGE PRIN"  90004071
"LARGE PRIN"  30025000162744
"LARGE PRIN"  30025000128349
```

Would anyone be able to help me out? I have a feeling this is a really silly problem but I can't figure it out at the momoent!

Comment: What are you expecting?  There are three `barcode`s for each `code`, so you get all three.

Comment: What data is in the items table?  It looks like the query is working as is.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this if you want a single record for each CODE and then list the bar codes for each.  Otherwise your query is working properly, if you have 3 barcodes for each code, you will get 3 rows for each code.

```
select code, GROUP_CONCAT(items.barcode) as barcodes

from   ohyeah_borrower_prefs 

       LEFT JOIN items 
       ON `items`.`inumber` = `ohyeah_borrower_prefs`.`inumber` 

WHERE (`ohyeah_borrower_prefs`.`biblionumber` = 13522)

GROUP BY code;
```